# How to modify "Security and Privacy" via apple script and or command line

Tags: macos, applescript

Relevant posts:

[Using AppleScript to modify settings/system preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214368/using-applescript-to-modify-settings-system-preferences)

[terminal command to change Security and Privacy Advanced Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865439/terminal-command-to-change-security-and-privacy-advanced-setting)

[Use AppleScript to change System Preferences without being visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711861/use-applescript-to-change-system-preferences-without-being-visible)

Within mac os, I would like to modify my "Privacy" settings within the "Security & Privacy" settings in an automated fashion... probably in the form of a script.

E.g. I would like to write some code that allows me to quickly allow/disallow application's access to my camera.

My attempts with apple script:

I cobbled together a script that allows me to open up "Security & Privacy" settings page. Further, I can specifically open up the privacy settings for the camera.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
  activate
  set securityPane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
  tell securityPane
    reveal anchor "Privacy_Camera"
  end tell
end tell
```

This was great! At this point it seemed like the rest should be easy. For application in list choose to allow/disallow access. However, I was unable to modify settings. From other apple script examples it seems that one must have an understanding of tabs, groups, scroll areas, and etc. **A reference for navigating UI elements on a particular window would be handy... is there one?**

The [first SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49214368/using-applescript-to-modify-settings-system-preferences) mentioned above was helpful it showed me how to list UI elements.

```
set myArray to {}
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    delay 2
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Security & Privacy" of application process "System Preferences"
            repeat with uiElem in entire contents as list
                set myArray to myArray & ((class of uiElem as string) & " : " & name of uiElem as string)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

However, attempts to navigate and modify the various elements(scroll areas, groups, checkboxes) was not very fruitful.

I feel as if I am very close, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

A couple of thoughts:

1) This seems a little overboard just to be able to change privacy settings.

2) Is there a more direct method from the command line?

2.a) I came across methods to modify settings in the sql database... I am not very familiar with sql databases... maybe I should be...

2.b) The method of the [2nd SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865439/terminal-command-to-change-security-and-privacy-advanced-setting) post mentioned above is more direct. It seems like I must learn more about mac os in order to understand how to utilize this option.

3) It does not need be to apple script... I am open to other suggestions.